# beamer blocks disposal in circle

Tags: beamer

I am happy with my beamer slides and I think blocks are nice to separate ideas...

But I've seen some Cisco presentations (most probably powerpoint) with like an image in the middle and then multiple blocks disposed around it (in a circle shape)

I think the effect is very nice, and I don't know how to do it in beamer:
do you have an idea?

The idea is to have this kind of shape:

```
C1  C2 C3
  \ | /
C4-Im-C5
  / | \
C6 C7  C8
```

Im is the image and all Cn are comments (and should be nice inside blocks)

Thank you
Louis

PS: a perfect solution should allow to place some `\pause` in the blocks, so that we have first the image, then first comment and so on...

Comment: I guess a TikZ solution is the best way to do this... `\pause` is probably not going to work, but more powerful overlay commands (`\onslide` etc) will certainly be available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The image can/should be done in TikZ and the overlaying can be done using the `\action` command (`\pause` is not quite smart enough here).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\action<+->{\node[fill=red,ellipse] (O) {Im};}
\foreach \text/\q in {$C_1$/135,$C_2$/90,$C_3$/45,$C_4$/180,$C_5$/0,$C_6$/225,$C_7$/270,$C_8$/315} {
    \action<+->{\draw (\q:2cm) node[fill=blue!20!white,draw,rectangle]  {\text} -- (O);}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Rabid dollar alert!  Seriously, wasn't there a question recently about putting node text in mathematics mode automatically?

Comment: @Andrew: lol.  I thought about that but the OP doesn't want a bunch of math expressions arrayed around a central node, he wants text.  So if he's cutting/pasting, he shouldn't have to undo the automatic putting of node text in math mode.  I probably should have avoided math mode altogether and just went with `C1/135,...`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed: thank you very much. I won't fear anymore to pass after Cisco guys ;)